# How to return a value from a callback that is passed a parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback

I have made a function square (that returns square of the number)and passed it into another function.

```
var num = 5;
  function square(x){
  return x*x;
}

function display(fn){
  console.log(fn())
}

display(function(){square(num)});
```

It is not returning me that squared value in display function instead it is returning me 'undefined'.

Comment: The function you passed to `display` isn't returning anything, thus `undefined`. change to `return square(num)`

Comment: func 1 shoud `return func2(param)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose the returned value here:

```
 display(function(){square(num)})
```

You either have to return it:

```
 display(function(){ return square(num)})
```

or you use an arrow function

```
 display(() => square(num));
```

or you bind the function:

```
 display(square.bind(null, num));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `function(){}` to call your function. 
It is only used to define a function.

Beside this you can just use the `fn` variable to log to the console, you don't have to use `fn()`

```
var num = 5;
function square(x){
    return x*x;
}

function display(fn){
    console.log(fn)
}

display(square(num));
```

It is also possible to return the value into a variable, if this makes it easier to read for you:

```
function square(x){
    return x*x;
}

function display(fn){
    console.log(fn)
}

var num = 5;
var calculationResult = square(num);
display(calculationResult);
```

Comment: How does this return `square(num)`? `display` doesn't return anything.

Comment: The squire function returns the value (25 for now) into the display function. So `fn = 25`. This results into `console.log(25)`

Answer (score 2):

Here. You just need to return the `square(num)` inside the `display` function.

```js
var num = 5;
  function square(x){
  return x*x;
}

function display(fn){
  console.log(fn());
}

display(function(){
  return square(num);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`display(function(){square(num)});`

In your code just write **return** keyword .

`display(function(){return square(num)});`

Above code will work fine